# Finite Automata Mixture Combinatorics

Tags: finite-automata, combinatorics

Hello Folks,
I am facing hard time in understanding this, basic question which says, how many possible finite automata ( DFA ) are there with two states X and Y, where X is always initial state with alphabet a and b, that accepts everything?

What i understand is:

Number of possible inputs possible: (a,X), (a,Y), (b,X), (b,Y) i.e. 4;

so each input has option of going on 2 states, which sums up to be: 2^4;

I know to find total number of DFA, we need is Total number of transition * number of final state.

so, according to me answer need to be 2^4 * 2^2 = 2^6;
but actual answer is 20 ? How it can be? Please throw some light on this !! Thankyou!!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the question also requires the automaton to accept everything. This means that if e.g., $X$ is not accepting, then you need to discount it.

Your count of the number of transition functions is correct, $2^4$. However, it's not true that the total number is $2^4$ times the number of final states, but rather the number of *options* for final states. Naively, this would be $4$: either both $X,Y$ are accepting, neither, just $X$ or just $Y$.

However, $X$ must be accepting, otherwise the empty word is not accepted. We now have to reason about whether $Y$ is accepting. If it is, then all transition functions are ok, and the automaton will accept everything. Thus, you have $2^4$ automata with $Y$ accepting.

If $Y$ is not accepting, then not all is lost - maybe $Y$ is not reachable from $X$. This happens when both transitions from $X$ are back to $X$. In this case, you can still point the transitions from $Y$ wherever you want, so you get $4$ additional DFAs.

So in total, you have $16+4=20$ options.